# DACPAC: Altering primary key results in rebuilding tables during deployment

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, deployment, clustered-primary-key

Question: Is there any better way to avoid rebuilding of table when clustered Index column is changed

Details:

We have Database project with all default settings.
There are tables with primary key consisting of ID and Date.

This date column is being changed from DateTime to DateTImeOffset.

When DACPAC generated by this DB project is used to deploy on tests system, it creates a temp  table, moves data from original to temp, modifies the clustered indexes, and moves data from temp to Original table.

This takes very long time and consumes a lot of diskspace.

Temp table name is like this
tmp_ms_xx_OriginalTablename

Script generated by DACPAC

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
 
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
 
CREATE TABLE [core].[tmp_ms_xx_Originaltable] (
    [SOurceTableKey] NVARCHAR (32)      NOT NULL,
    [tableResource]    NVARCHAR (MAX)     NOT NULL,
    [tableVersion]     INT                NULL,
    [ValidFrom]       DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NOT NULL,
   
    CONSTRAINT [tmp_ms_xx_constraint_PK_Originaltable_11] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SOurceTableKey] ASC, [ValidFrom] ASC) );

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
           FROM   [core].[Originaltable])
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [core].[tmp_ms_xx_Originaltable] ([SOurceTableKey], [ValidFrom], [tableResource], [tableVersion],
[ValidTo], [LoadProtocolID], [HashDiff], [RecordSrc], [LastUpdated])
        SELECT   [SOurceTable
```

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 9002, Level 17, State 2, Line 23 The transaction log for database 'AIPCDataServiceDB' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script: